# ASP.NET MVC 3 , partial views and Count()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

Here is my code in view

```
@model QA.posts
@{var c = Model.Count(o => o.parent == Model.id);}
```

Why the `Count()` method is not available in this area ?
I am using that in regular view(s).

**EDIT :** 
It is my mistake , I have `IEnumerable<QA.posts>` and want to send each item to `partial views` in foreach statement. It is normal that partial views just get a single class and `count()` doesn't work. I am going to find solution to send the count separately to view.

Comment: What type does `QA.posts` derive from? And that's an odd looking class name...

Comment: this is the mapped class to "posts" table and auto generated with Entity framework

Comment: @Mironline your view have '@model QA.posts' or '@model IEnumerable<QA.posts>' ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to import System.Linq

```
@using System.Linq
@model QA.posts
@{var c = Model.Count(o => o.parent == Model.id);}
```

My guess is that `Model` is an `Enumerable` data type which means in order to use [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx), you must import the `System.Linq` namespace.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you may need to change the model declaration:

```
@model IList<QA.posts> // Or whatever you want the Model to be list-wise.
```

That way, Model is now a list of Posts which means you can now use `Count` without the need to import System.Linq.

If that still doesn't help, then could you please show the code for your QA.posts model class?

Comment: the QA.Posts is the auto generated class with entity framework for single table , I would like to use the "partial views" in "foreach" statement and I think the @model should be a class not a generic list .

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help any further. Using `System.Linq` has worked for me in the past, when using EF classes and extension methods such as `Count`.

Comment: Jason Evans , thank you very much indeed for your help . I updated my questions . the problem was I sent the 'single class' to 'partial view' and it is obvious single hasn't got the 'count' method , I solved this issue by sending 'count' with 'ViewDataDictionary'. thank you again .